# Golang - Copy exec output to a buffer

Tags: go

I'm writing a function that exec's a program and returns stdout and stderr. It also has the option to display the output to the console. I'm clearly not waiting on something, as if I run the function twice in a row, the outputs are different. Here's a sample program, replace the dir var with a dir with a lot of files to fill up the buffers:

```
func main() {
    dir := "SOMEDIRECTORYWITHALOTOFFILES"
    out, err := run("ls -l "+dir, true)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("run returned %s", err)
    }
    log.Printf("Out: %s", out)
    out2, err := run("ls -l "+dir, false)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("run returned %s", err)
    }
    log.Printf("Out2: %s", out2)
    if out != out2 {
        log.Fatalf("Out mismatch")
    }
}

func run(cmd string, displayOutput bool) (string, error) {
    var command *exec.Cmd
    command = exec.Command("/bin/sh", "-c", cmd)
    var output bytes.Buffer

    stdout, err := command.StdoutPipe()
    if err != nil {
        return "", fmt.Errorf("Unable to setup stdout for command: %v", err)
    }
    go func() {
        if displayOutput == true {
            w := io.MultiWriter(os.Stdout, &output)
            io.Copy(w, stdout)
        } else {
            output.ReadFrom(stdout)
        }
    }()

    stderr, err := command.StderrPipe()
    if err != nil {
        return "", fmt.Errorf("Unable to setup stderr for command: %v", err)
    }
    go func() {
        if displayOutput == true {
            w := io.MultiWriter(os.Stderr, &output)
            io.Copy(w, stderr)
        } else {
            output.ReadFrom(stderr)
        }
    }()
    err = command.Run()
    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }
    return output.String(), nil
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simplified and working revision of your example. Note that the test command was swapped out so that I could test within Windows and that your error checks have been omitted only for brevity.

The key change is that a `sync.WaitGroup` is preventing the `run` function from printing the output and returning until the goroutine has indicated that it's finished.

```go
func main() {
    dir := "c:\\windows\\system32"
    command1 := exec.Command("cmd", "/C", "dir", "/s", dir)
    command2 := exec.Command("cmd", "/C", "dir", "/s", dir)
    out1, _ := run(command1)
    out2, _ := run(command2)
    log.Printf("Length [%d] vs [%d]\n", len(out1), len(out2))
}

func run(cmd *exec.Cmd) (string, error) {
    var output bytes.Buffer
    var waitGroup sync.WaitGroup

    stdout, _ := cmd.StdoutPipe()
    writer := io.MultiWriter(os.Stdout, &output)

    waitGroup.Add(1)
    go func() {
        defer waitGroup.Done()
        io.Copy(writer, stdout)
    }()

    cmd.Run()
    waitGroup.Wait()
    return output.String(), nil
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I see some problems:

- You should be waiting for the goroutines to finish (e.g., using
  `sync.WaitGroup`).
- You're accessing `output` concurrently in two
  goroutines, which is not safe.

You could collect `stdout` and `stderr` in two separate buffers and return them separately, if that works for what you're trying to do.